# Add long chapter name in table of content instead of short verision

Tags: thesis

I am using `\documentclass{scrreprt}`.
Now I have `\Chapter[short-title A]{complete-title B}`, how can I display the `complete-title B` in the table of content instead of displaying the `short-title A`?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the short title: `\chapter{title B}`.

The typical classes (`book, scrreprt` etc) have one optional chapter argument which can be used to specify the ToC and header entry.

The `memoir` class (a superset of `book`) allows 2 optional arguments to the `\chapter` coommand which can be used to specify the ToC, header and title entry.

```
\chapter[toc-title][head-title]{title}
```

I think perhaps you want something (without any typos) along the lines of:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
% stuff
\begin{document}
\tableofcontent
% stuff
\chapter[title in ToC][title in header]{title in doc}
```

Read the manual (`texdoc memoir`) section 6.2 Sectional divisions for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `headings=optiontohead`.

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontohead]{scrreprt}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[Short title for head]{Long title that we also want 
  to write unchanged in the table of contents}

Some text

\clearpage

Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

You can also define different titles for the head, the TOC and the chapter proper.

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontohead]{scrreprt}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter[
  head={Short title for head},
  tocentry={Long title, but we want to shorten it in the toc}
]{Long title that we also want
  to write unchanged in the table of contents}

Some text

\clearpage

Some text

\end{document}
```